# MSBuild CreateItem condition include based on config file

Tags: msbuild, createitem

I'm trying to select a list of test dlls that contain corresponding config files

MyTest.Tests.dll
MyTest.Tests.config

I have to use a createItem as the dlls are not available at the time of the script loading

```
<CreateItem Include="$(AssemblyFolder)\*.Tests.dll"
            Condition="???"
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TestBinariesWithConfig"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Is there a condition I can use or is this the wrong approach?

Thanks
Mac

EDIT:

ok, to clarify, I need to construct a xUnit.Net project file. I need to do this because I'm running the tests through the xUnit.Console runner via nCover (don't ask!) but the long and short of it is I can only use a project file. The problem I'm having is when I have a test dll with an associated .config file. Without the config file, the test runner will fail.

This means I need to conditionally add an extra attribute (config-file) in the test project file.

The project template file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xunit>
  <assemblies>
<!-- SAMPLE    <assembly filename="Tests.dll" shadow-copy="false" config-file="Tests.dll.config" />     -->
<!-- @TARGETS@ -->
  </assemblies>
</xunit>
```

The FileUpdate task for the test dlls with no config file.

```
<FileUpdate
  Files="$(AssemblyFolder)\$(XUnitProjectFileName)"
  Regex="&lt;!-- @TARGETS@ --&gt;"
  ReplacementText="&lt;!-- @TARGETS@ --&gt;%0D%0A&lt;assembly filename='$(AssemblyFolder)\%(TestBinaries.FileName)%(TestBinaries.Extension)' shadow-copy='false' /&gt;"
  />
```

So I need a way to conditionally add the extra attribute in the FileUpdate task depending on whether there is a corresponding config file for the test dll.

Comment: Feedback on my answer would be welcome.

Comment: Sorry Filburt, bit rude there. I actually took the easy way out and ended up creating a custom MSBuild task to do the job of generating the project file before I read your answer. I didn't know about using metadata though so your approach looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the MSBuild Task output as a source for your CreateItem Task.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReferences Include="*.*proj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="BuildMyProjects">
        <MSBuild
            Projects="@(ProjectReferences)"
            Targets="Build">
            <Output
                TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"
                ItemName="AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects" />
        </MSBuild>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="AddConfigMetadata" DependsOnTargets="BuildMyProjects">
        <CreateItem
            Include="@(AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects)"
            AdditionalMetadata="config-file=%(Identity).config">
            <Output
                TaskParameter="Include"
                ItemName="MySourceItemsWithMetadata" />
        </CreateItem>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="WhatEverYouLikeToDo" DependsOnTargets="AddConfigMetadata">
        <Message Text="%(MySourceItemsWithMetadata.config-file)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem discription isn't really clear to me, but your .Tests.dll's should always be available because you should build your project first before testing it. Whenever you've build your project, you can run the CreateItem task. The CreateItem is a good approach to retrieve the .dll's but you don't need a condition for it.

So in your build file you should have something like this:
- Build project/solution
-> .dll's will be created
- Execute CreateItem
- Do something with the Item

With this awnser I'm assuming you're trying to automate your tests?